Question about model relationships in Sequelize-typescript
After using Sequelize I decided to try Sequelize-typescript for myself, but I realized one thing: I don't fully understand how it works.
The essence of the question: there are two models and some relation between them (One Role refers to many Users). In the documentation it says that I should specify fields like users for Role and role for User, but I can't use them
// user.model.ts

import {
  Table,
  Column,
  Model,
  DataType,
  IsEmail,
  CreatedAt,
  UpdatedAt,
  ForeignKey,
  BelongsTo,
  HasMany,
} from "sequelize-typescript";
import Role from "./role.model";
import Thread from "./thread.model";
import Message from "./message.model";

@Table({
  timestamps: true,
  tableName: "users",
  modelName: "user"
})
export default class User extends Model {
  @Column({
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
    type: DataType.INTEGER
  })
  declare id: number;

  @Column({
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
    defaultValue: "Unknown",
    type: DataType.STRING
  })
  declare nickname: string;

  @Column({
    defaultValue: "Unknown",
    type: DataType.STRING
  })
  declare avatar: string;

  @IsEmail
  @Column({
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
    defaultValue: "Unknown",
    type: DataType.STRING
  })
  declare email: string;

  @Column({
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: "Unknown",
    type: DataType.STRING
  })
  declare password: string;

  @CreatedAt
  declare created_at: Date;

  @UpdatedAt
  declare updated_at: Date;

  @ForeignKey(() => Role)
  @Column({
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataType.INTEGER
  })
  declare role_id: number;

  @BelongsTo(() => Role)
  declare role: Role;

  @HasMany(() => Thread)
  declare threads: Thread[];

  @HasMany(() => Message)
  declare messages: Message[];
}

// role.model.ts

import { Table, Column, Model, DataType, Length, HasMany } from "sequelize-typescript";
import User from "./user.model";

@Table({
  timestamps: false,
  tableName: "roles",
  modelName: "Role"
})
export default class Role extends Model {
  @Column({
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
    type: DataType.INTEGER
  })
  declare id: number;

  @Length({ min: 1, max: 20 })
  @Column({
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: "Unknown",
    type: DataType.STRING
  })
  declare name: string;

  @HasMany(() => User, "role_id")
  declare users: User[];
}

After searching for a string in the database, when I try to call user.role, for example, it gives undefined.

Then why do I need this field? Only to indicate that the relationship between models?
If the answer to the first question is "Yes", is there an adequate way to specify relationships without these useless fields?

